# How to create Id based on equal values in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have  list of names 
A1 -properties, B1- first name C1 -last name ,

I need to add to this list a new id column however this id should be unique to each user . So for example if I have John, Smith  5 times in the list his ID will be always the same all 5 times.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: What if there are two different people named John Smith?

Comment: Assumptions there is none.Current application uses the names as  key so this problem do not  exist.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got simple solution. 
Lets assume all last names are unique (if not just concatenate first and last name together)

Step 1. I just sort the data by the unique field in my case C . (Last name or concatenated one)
step 2. I give a value to first ID lets say my Id column is J and my first id will be one .

Then in second row I write something like this `=IF(C3=C2,J2,J2+1)`

I see a lot of solutions online but this looks like the most simple one.